# Changing cluster point label font size in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I have a cluster with a lot of data points that overlap and are therefore hard to read. I have been attempting to reduce the font size using the "theme" function but so far I have only been able to change everything but the label point font size:

```
clust_1975F <-  kmeans(df_1975F, 3, nstart = 25)
X11()
(fviz_cluster(clust_1975F, data = df_1975F)
    + ggtitle("Cluster for Females in 1975") 
    + theme(text = element_text(size = 5)))
```

Cluster output with the use of "theme" function:

[image: 1]

Comment: It may be helpful to provide a reproducible dataset so others can help you more. Here is a guide for sharing the `dput` of your data: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP, you're looking for `labelsize=`, which is an argument for the `fviz_cluster()` function from the `factoextra` package.  I encourage you to [check the documentation for the function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/factoextra/versions/1.0.7/topics/fviz_cluster), which has a lot of examples and a good description of all the arguments used for that function.

Here's an example with `iris` that is from [the documentation page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/factoextra/versions/1.0.7/topics/fviz_cluster):

```
library(factoextra)

set.seed(123)
data("iris")
head(iris)
iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, -5])
km.res <- kmeans(iris.scaled, 3, nstart = 10)
fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5], ellipse.type = "norm")
```

[image]

To change the size of the text (let's make it larger here), you just need to run `fviz_cluster()` with `labelsize` set to something larger than the default setting (listed in [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/factoextra/versions/1.0.7/topics/fviz_cluster) as `12`).

```
fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5], ellipse.type = "norm", labelsize = 22)
```

[image]